# How to have lots of data in android app

Tags: android, save

I want to write an android application that contains lots of data. 
For example, I've about 30 categories, each category has about 50 items and each items consist of 10 text pages and 5-8 pictures.

I want my app to work offline and doesn't need internet connection.

What is the best and safest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sqlite database. Database is the best way to keep big amount of data structured. 
You can put all your text data in tables. You can also put images to tables as blob or put images to assets folder and database will store path to image.

Just create sqlite database with all needed data on your PC and then attach it to your android app. You can easily find lots of information how to work with sqlite in android.

Comment: thanks every one for you answers,What is the simplest way to save and enter all of my datas to sqlite? If I want to do it on java, it's miserable , is there any otehr way to do this ? like phpmyadmin that we can put our datas to it ?

Comment: You can create sqlite in PC, like in phpmyadmin. Just look for sqlite manager in google and choose what you like. I used the FireFox add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ . It is cross platform, free and easy to use.

Comment: thanks you , what do you suggest for images ? I should make different size for different devices ?

Comment: It depends, give me an example of image. You can take images 1920x1080 (most popular devices) and then reduce it (with saving ratio) for other devices in code.

Answer (score 0):

If You have every thing Hardcode . then you can put them all in assests folder in your project and then can read from code any file you want by different methods avaiable easily .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use sqlite databse which is easy . You can store large texts and images as well . 
Other option is to store all this data in xml and use it and images in drawable folder.
But managing data will be difficult so try using database .

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/  you could refer this link for sqlite database tables